# AWS Elastic IP Unable to Send Traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that had a dynamic public IP. Due to changing requirements I assigned a new Elastic IP. I shut down the instance and restarted it. The console now shows the new IP and no longer the old, dynamic one.

Problem is now I can not ping nor curl/wget to the public Internet any longer from this instance. I do have an outgoing rule for port 80 and 443 setup. I also allow ICMP in both directions.

I have a load balancer setup in another instance. That instance can access the problematic instance over the private IP no problem.

I did notice that while all my other instances list their public IP (dynamic or Elastic) the instance in question lists "ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com". Not sure what to make of that...

What could be my issue?

Comment: Perhaps you don;t have your webserver set to run on boot. You should SSH in and check this out. You won't be able to ping your instance unless you have it allowed in the security group (ICMP).

Comment: The server runs its services fine as they were setup before. There is a Nginx load balancer in front of this instance which it can access fine.

As far as pings go I have tried both with and without ICMP allowed (both incoming and outgoing).

Comment: If another instance in your VPC can talk to this instance, your issue is likely related to a firewall. It could be a firewall on the instance itself, security group rules, or even NACLs. If not, you should check the route table of the subnet in which this instance is placed to ensure it has a route sending 0.0.0.0/0 to the IGW.

Comment: Is this question better suited for Server Fault?

Comment: Sorry but I am ignorant of the difference. I will look into that for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not seeing the public IP show up in the console for the system, but instead are seeing the hostname as you mention, it means that your public IP is NOT assigned to the instance. Suggest you go to the Elastic IPs section of the console and re-attach the EIP to the instance.

Note, if you are not running in a VPC, when you reboot the instance, the EIP will drop off the instance.

Comment: Disassociating and reassociating the Elastic IP did the job. Thanks for the direction!